# Flutter tried calling data receiver null

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

the flutter code below must show a view the problem is that when I run the code and click on the button to view the view index = 1 I get the following error:

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown during a scheduler
> callback: The getter 'data' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried
> calling: data
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:68:5)
> #1      ThemeProvider.of (package:animated_theme_switcher/src/theme_provider.dart:27:22)

now the error appears only in the display of this view, what is it due to and how can I solve it?

**ChangeView.dart**

```
..
 //Function call new view with index=1
 void onItemPressed(BuildContext context, {int index}) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        break;
      case 1:
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => UserScreen()
        ));
        break;
    }
  }
..
```

**User.dart**

```
class UserScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.init(context,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        allowFontScaling: true);

    var profileInfo = Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: kSpacingUnit.w * 10,
            width: kSpacingUnit.w * 10,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: kSpacingUnit.w * 3),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: kSpacingUnit.w * 5,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/avatar.png'),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: Container(
                    height: kSpacingUnit.w * 2.5,
                    width: kSpacingUnit.w * 2.5,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      heightFactor: kSpacingUnit.w * 1.5,
                      widthFactor: kSpacingUnit.w * 1.5,
                      child: Icon(
                        LineAwesomeIcons.pen,
                        color: kDarkPrimaryColor,
                        size: ScreenUtil().setSp(kSpacingUnit.w * 1.5),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: kSpacingUnit.w * 2),
          Text(
            'Nicolas Adams',
            style: kTitleTextStyle,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: kSpacingUnit.w * 0.5),
          Text(
            'nicolasadams@gmail.com',
            style: kCaptionTextStyle,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: kSpacingUnit.w * 2),
          Container(
            height: kSpacingUnit.w * 4,
            width: kSpacingUnit.w * 20,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(kSpacingUnit.w * 3),
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Upgrade to PRO',
                style: kButtonTextStyle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    var themeSwitcher = ThemeSwitcher(
      builder: (context) {
        return AnimatedCrossFade(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          crossFadeState:
          ThemeProvider.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
              ? CrossFadeState.showFirst
              : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
          firstChild: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () =>
                ThemeSwitcher.of(context).changeTheme(theme: kLightTheme),
            child: Icon(
              LineAwesomeIcons.sun,
              size: ScreenUtil().setSp(kSpacingUnit.w * 3),
            ),
          ),
          secondChild: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () =>
                ThemeSwitcher.of(context).changeTheme(theme: kDarkTheme),
            child: Icon(
              LineAwesomeIcons.moon,
              size: ScreenUtil().setSp(kSpacingUnit.w * 3),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );

    var header = Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(width: kSpacingUnit.w * 3),
        Icon(
          LineAwesomeIcons.arrow_left,
          size: ScreenUtil().setSp(kSpacingUnit.w * 3),
        ),
        profileInfo,
        themeSwitcher,
        SizedBox(width: kSpacingUnit.w * 3),
      ],
    );

    return ThemeSwitchingArea(
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: kSpacingUnit.w * 5),
                header,
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      UserListItem(
                        icon: LineAwesomeIcons.user_shield,
                        text: 'Privacy',
                      ),
                      UserListItem(
                        icon: LineAwesomeIcons.history,
                        text: 'Purchase History',
                      ),
                      UserListItem(
                        icon: LineAwesomeIcons.question_circle,
                        text: 'Help & Support',
                      ),
                      UserListItem(
                        icon: LineAwesomeIcons.cog,
                        text: 'Settings',
                      ),
                      UserListItem(
                        icon: LineAwesomeIcons.user_plus,
                        text: 'Invite a Friend',
                      ),
                      UserListItem(
                        icon: LineAwesomeIcons.alternate_sign_out,
                        text: 'Logout',
                        hasNavigation: false,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UserListItem.dart**

```
class UserListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final String text;
  final bool hasNavigation;

  const UserListItem({
    Key key,
    this.icon,
    this.text,
    this.hasNavigation = true,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: kSpacingUnit.w * 5.5,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: kSpacingUnit.w * 4,
      ).copyWith(
        bottom: kSpacingUnit.w * 2,
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: kSpacingUnit.w * 2,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(kSpacingUnit.w * 3),
        color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            this.icon,
            size: kSpacingUnit.w * 2.5,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: kSpacingUnit.w * 1.5),
          Text(
            this.text,
            style: kTitleTextStyle.copyWith(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          if (this.hasNavigation)
            Icon(
              LineAwesomeIcons.angle_right,
              size: kSpacingUnit.w * 2.5,
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `UserScreen` inside `ThemeSwitcher` (where you pass the value in `crossFadeState`) use `ThemeProvider` like this

`ThemeProvider.themeOf(context).brightness == Brightness.dark`

Comment: your solution is already written in the code

Comment: did you wrap your `Material app` widget? or you can wrap user screen like this  `MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (_) => ThemeConsumer(child: UserScreen()),
),`

Comment: what is theme consumer?

Comment: I think you should reconsider reading the theme_provider doc. I guess you miss use app context and theme provider context . link:https://pub.dev/packages/theme_provider